# The usage of "excess"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Suppose A and B usually come together. For example 10 units of A and 10 units of B. However, sometimes you may have 15 units of A and 10 units of B.

> I want to say that A is in excess .... B. Or there is an excess of A ... B

I don't know how to fill the blanks above. Is it "to", "than"?

Comment: The standard preposition would be *an excess of A **over** B*, but for your exact context this isn't very natural anyway. Just say *there are **more of** A than [there are of] B*.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a single word that does a good job filling either of those blanks. As fumblefingers said, the closest you will probably get is "over" as in

> There is an excess of A over B.

But this really does not sound natural. I would recommend you use two or three words; specifically, "relative to" and "with regard to" or "in regard to" work well here:

> We have an excess of A relative to B
>
> There is an excess of A with regard to B

Another option is to rearange the sentence a little:

> We have A in excess of B

All of these work well for this situation and are precise. In this case, your ratio is 1:1, so it would actually be easier and just as accurate to simply say one is greater than the other:

> We have more A than B.

While not correct in a formal manner, this technique would still be a good way to say that you had too much A for B even if the ratio were not 1:1 in many contexts, as the ratio is implied.